# approximate value of integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I came across while solving some problem that I need the exact/ approximate value of following integral. I need an upper bound of $-0.4$ or $-0.5$. Is there some way or programming tools.

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \ln\left(\dfrac{x^6+8x^4+16x^2+4}{x^6+8x^4+15x^2+6}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

This is not homework problem. Just while solving some calculus problem, it came out

Comment: It does have an elementary antiderivative and closed form solution provided by Wolfram for example (although it seems horrible).

Comment: A very simple bound is found by seeing that its monotonely increasing and is $0$ at $x=\sqrt{2}$ so its bounded below by $\log(4/6)\cdot\sqrt{2}\approx -0.57$ and bounded above by $0\cdot \sqrt{2} = 0$.

Comment: $$4 \text{RootSum}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+8 \text{$\#$1}^4+16 \text{$\#$1}^2+4\&,\frac{2 \text{$\#$1}^4 \log
   (x-\text{$\#$1})+8 \text{$\#$1}^2 \log (x-\text{$\#$1})+3 \log (x-\text{$\#$1})}{3 \text{$\#$1}^5+16 \text{$\#$1}^3+16
   \text{$\#$1}}\&\right]+x \log \left(\frac{x^6+8 x^4+16 x^2+4}{x^6+8 x^4+15 x^2+6}\right)-2 \sqrt{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\left(\sqrt{6}-2\right) \sqrt{2 \left(3+\sqrt{6}\right)} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3-\sqrt{6}}}\right)-\sqrt{6-2 \sqrt{6}} \left(2+\sqrt{6}\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{6}}}\right)$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Is all I can get. I think this is hardly a closed form :/

Comment: @MaximillianJanisch I mean it's a way to write the solution solely in terms of the sum of elementary functions although evaluated at complex arguments (I did say horrible).

Comment: If you just need an upper bound, Riemann sums/trapezoidal rule/Simpson's rule should work fine since for $x > 0$ you have a monotonically increasing function.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch This is definitely a closed form solution... It is just written in terms of constants that are roots of a polynomial of degree 6.

Comment: @PierreCarre and @ PeterForeman Fair enough, sadly there is no way to express this as a combination of $n$th roots and addition, multiplication and trig. functions

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Finally it comes down to the fact that *closed form solution* is an ambiguous definition... It requires a list of acceptable functions, and you are going one step further by putting conditions on how constants are actually computed.

Comment: @PierreCarre This is a very nice comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write numerator and denominator as
$$\dfrac{x^6+8x^4+16x^2+4}{x^6+8x^4+15x^2+6}=\frac{(x^2+a)(x^2+b)(x^2+c)}{(x^2+d)(x^2+e)(x^2+f)}$$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are all positive numbers.

Expand the logarithm to face
$$I(p)=\int_0^{\sqrt 2} \log(x^2+p)=\sqrt{2} (\log (p+2)-2)+2 \sqrt{p} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{p}}\right)$$

If I am not mistaken, $a,b,c$ are given by
$$\frac{8}{3}-\frac{8}{3} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{32}\right)\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad k=0,1,2$$ and $c,d,e$ by 
$$\frac{8}{3}-\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{19} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{53}{19 \sqrt{19}}\right)\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad k=0,1,2$$

**Edit**

If we just want an approximate value of the integral, using the simplest Padé approximant built around $x=1$ (more or less the midpoint of the integration range), we have
$$\dfrac{x^6+8x^4+16x^2+4}{x^6+8x^4+15x^2+6}\sim \frac{\frac{3389 (x-1)^2}{4520}+\frac{4691 (x-1)}{3390}+\frac{29}{30}}{\frac{1799
   (x-1)^2}{2260}+\frac{2177 (x-1)}{1695}+1}$$

Thus, completing the squares, we have
$$\log\left(\dfrac{x^6+8x^4+16x^2+4}{x^6+8x^4+15x^2+6}\right)\,dx \sim\log\left(\dfrac{a (x-b)^2+c}{d (x-e)^2+f}\right)\,dx$$ and
$$J=\int \log \left(a (x-b)^2+c\right)\,dx$$ is given by
$$J=(x-b) \log \left(a (x-b)^2+c\right)+\frac{2 \sqrt{c} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a} }{\sqrt{c}}(x-b)\right)}{\sqrt{a}}-2 (x-b)$$
This should lead to a value equal to $-0.212276$ to be compared to the exact $−0.211212$ given by Wolfram Alpha (this makes  a relative error of $0.5$%.

Comment: $d, e, f$ should be
$$\frac 8 3 + \frac {2 \sqrt {19}} 3 \cos \left(
 \frac {2 \pi k} 3 - \frac 1 3 \arccos \frac {26} {19 \sqrt {19}} \right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Ask [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28%28x%5E6%2B8*x%5E4+%2B+16*x%5E2%2B4%29%2F%28x%5E6%2B8*x%5E4+%2B+15*x%5E2%2B6%29%29+from+x%3D0+to+sqrt%282%29) or a computer algebra package at the university...

It gives $-0.211212$ as an approximation.